# Is there any acid which releases a gas when neutralized with hydroxide?

Tags: acid-base

Out of curiosity, is there any acid which releases a gas upon neutralization with sodium hydroxide? Most acids that I know of release hydrogen upon reaction with metals, but not upon reaction with alkalis like sodium hydroxide.

Comment: Look at the problem in reverse: take a substance that is a gas in ambient conditions, then add a proton to it. Whatever you get will fit the bill, such as the ammonium and phosphonium ions Jan mentions in his answer. In principle, protonated carbon dioxide ($\ce{HCO2^+}$), protonated helium ($\ce{HeH^+}$), protonated hydrogen ($\ce{H3^+}$), etc. all work, though most of these examples will be quite artificial. Furthermore, there is a simple but fundamental fact which makes acids deprotonating into gasses less usual; there just aren't that many gaseous substances in ambient conditions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest and most obvious answer is the ammonium ion, closely followed by the phosphonium ion $\ce{PH4+}$. Both are acids as defined by the Arrhenius theory and by the Brønsted-Lowry theory; however, they always require a counterion. Upon proton displacement, they form gaseous compounds — $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{PH3}$, respectively — which will diffuse out of solution given enough time.

The solubility of ammonia in water is much higher than that of carbon dioxide, though; so it takes longer for ammonia to be released and no visible bubbling occurs. Yet, the gas evolution can be shown by sticking a moist indicator paper above the solution; fumes of ammonia will colour it whichever colour means *basic* on that paper.

$$\begin{align}\ce{NH4+ + OH- &-> NH3 (g) ^ + H2O}\tag{1}\\[1.2em]
\ce{PH4+ + H2O &-> PH3 (g) ^ + H3O+}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

A less obvious answer and maybe a bit of a stretch is the monochloride of oxalic acid, $\ce{ClCOCOOH}$. This compound is not stable; however, its basic structural motif is formed in many organic mechanisms, e.g. in the Swern oxidation as a $\ce{DMS}$ adduct ($\ce{Cl-CO-COO-S^+Me2}$). Once a chloride ion attacks sulfur nucleophilicly and thereby displaces what formally would be the monoanion of oxalic acid monochloride, this breaks down into carbon dioxide, carbon monoxide and chloride.

$$\ce{Cl- + Me2S^+-OCO-CO-Cl -> ClS^+Me2 + CO2 ^ + CO ^ + Cl-}\tag{3}$$